# Transformation from vector $x$ to its Vandermonde matrix $V(x)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, matrix-equations, numerical-linear-algebra

Consider a vector $x \in \mathbb{R}^N$ and the Vandermonde matrix $V(x)$

$$V(x)= [1 \; x \; x^2 \cdots x^{N-1}]$$

where the power of each vector is to be considered element-wise.
Can I write the transformation $V: \mathbb{R}^N \to  \mathbb{R}^{N \times N} $ only in terms of matrix/vector multiplications?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the kind of thing you're looking for, but if $A = \operatorname{diag}(x)$ and $b$ is the column-vector of all $1$s, then $V(x)$ is the [controllability matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Controllability#Continuous_linear_time-invariant_(LTI)_systems) associated with $A$ and $b$.

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out. What I am searching is slightly different. I was wondering whether I can express the Vandermonde matrix $V$ in a compact form which is function of the vector $x$. For instance $V= A x b^\top$, for some $A$ and $b$. Or some other transformation.

Comment: Keep in mind that any matrix of the form $vw^T$ has rank $1$ (whereas Vandermonde matrices have full rank generically), so the kind of form you've suggested is impossible. It's unclear how flexible "some other transformation" is as a category, though

Comment: Somehow I would like to express a Vandermonde constraint in an optimization problem, where the variable is though the vector $x$ and not the overall Vandermonde matrix derived from it. I was thinking to link the Vandermonde constraint to an Hankel constraint, but I am not sure that might help

Comment: Perhaps it would be best for you to post a question that details the actual optimization problem that you're interested in, or at least edit this question to add in that information. It sounds like you're looking for some kind of optimal polynomial given other constraints